# Legal documents confirming previous/maiden name (uk)

Tags: marriage, name

My wife is enrolling at university, however her previous qualifications were earned whilst she had her maiden name. They say they want to see a marriage certificate to confirm the name change, but we've just moved house and can't find it anywhere.

Assuming the university will accept any legal documents confirming the change in name, what is the easiest/fastest/cheapest option? Would a marriage certificate reissue be the only option?

Thanks.

Comment: The marriage certificate is the document that effected the name change, is it not?  There would likely be no other document that lists both her married and maiden names, but if there is one, you might talk them into accepting it.

Comment: That is the documented that affected the change, yes, and a reissue is possible. I guess in short, my question is "are there alternative means of proof"? E.g. Those that change their name by other means such as deed poll, is that also their only means of proof?

Answer (score 1):

For less than £10, you can [order a copy of your marriage certificate](https://www.gov.uk/order-copy-birth-death-marriage-certificate) from the [General Register Office](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/default.asp).

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this, but we would likely need to do the expedited version which is thrice the price but currently the best option. This is why I was explicitly asking for alternatives.